# How to show search filter above table instead of display under table header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I work on asp.net MVC project . I face issue I can't show search filter above header

meaning show search filters first then show header of table then data .

so Search filter will be first row after that display table with header .

so what changes I can do to display search filters above header of table ?

my code details

```
 new DataTable('#dtbl', {
            "dom": 'rtip',
            "order": [[0, 'desc'], [5, 'asc']],
            initComplete: function () {
                $('#dtbl tfoot tr').insertAfter($('#dtbl thead tr'))
                this.api()
                    .columns()
                    .every(function () {
                        let column = this;
                        let title = column.footer().textContent;
                        let input = document.createElement('input');
                        input.placeholder = title;
                        column.footer().replaceChildren(input);
                        input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
                            if (column.search() !== this.value) {
                                column.search(input.value).draw();
                            }
                        });
                    });
            }
        });

 <table id="dtbl" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="width:100%;padding-left:5px;
padding-right:7px;">
        <thead>
            <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">

                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Request No
                </th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Employee No
                </th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Employee Name
                </th>
               

            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">

                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestNo)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpID)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpName)
                    </td>
                   

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
                <tr>
                <th>Request No</th>
                <th>Employee No</th>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
            </tr>

            </tfoot>
    </table>
```

expected result as below :

[image: show above search header]

Answer (score 0):

Make room:

```
 <thead>
    <tr id="searchFiltersRow"></tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Request No</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Employee No</th>
        <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Employee Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

and add the th in your every

```
initComplete: function () {
  let $searchFiltersRow = $('#searchFiltersRow');
  this.api().columns().every(function () {

    ....

   $searchFiltersRow.append($('<th>').append(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of code is responsible for filter placement:

```
$('#dtbl tfoot tr').insertAfter($('#dtbl thead tr'))
```

Since the ask was about placing it as the first row of the table header, so the code should be updated to:

```
$('#dtbl tfoot tr').insertBefore($('#dtbl thead tr'))
```